# How to send a Y keystroke to dos command with a [YN} answer?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am using the deltree command which expects the user to confirm with a Y or N.

I tried 'echo Y | deltree ....' but got a "The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe" error.

Is there another way?

Comment: Sounds like an 'rm -rf' type accident that I had waiting to happen again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[deltree /Y ...](http://www.computerhope.com/deltree.htm)

Answer (score 1):

/S = Removes all directories and files in the specified directory in addition to the directory itself. Used to remove a directory tree.

/Q = Quiet mode, do not ask if OK to remove a directory tree with /S.

Comment: These options are not available. It seems it's a different deltree.